# How can I compare two lists that contain sets?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare two lists that each contain multiple sets, I am sorting the list as a whole by length and the sets in the list, but for some reason it is not working. Here is an example

`[{'b', 'a'}, {'c', 'd', 'a'}, {'e', 'c', 'a'}] == [{'b', 'a'}, {'c', 'e', 'a'}, {'c', 'd', 'a'}]`

This outputs
`False`

But I was expecting for it to return true, since both contain the same sets of elements.

Comment: The lists are in different orders. Of course they're not equivalent.

Comment: Do you also expect `[1, 2, 3] == [1, 3, 2]`? Why?

Comment: Im aware, but Ive used sorted() to try and order them but it wont happen.

Comment: `sorted` creates a new list rather than sorting in place, and also sets don't have a total ordering. But if you want to compare whether two things contain all the same elements, and don't care about order... aren't you already using something in your code with behaviour like that?

Comment: `<` on sets is a partial ordering, not a total ordering, so `sorted` on a list of sets produces an effectively random result.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have a typo. Shouldn't both sets have to be written exactly the same for this to work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).